# ${x_n} \to x$ weakly, why does $T{x_n} \to Tx$ weakly?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

If $T \in B(X,Y)$  and ${x_n} \to x$ weakly, why does $T{x_n} \to Tx$  weakly?

Comment: If $\lambda \in Y'$ (or $Y^\ast$, whatever notation you use), what can you say about $\lambda\circ T$?

Answer (score 3):

Note that $x_n \to x$ weakly means that for every $f \in X'$, we have $f(x_n) \to f(x)$.

Now, note that for any $g \in Y'$, we have
$g(Tx_n) = g \circ T(x_n)$, and that $g \circ T \in X'$.  From there, we simply apply the definition.